# Regex for 10 digit phone number with variable spacing

Tags: regex

I need to validate that a string follows these rules:

- contains numerals
- may optionally contain any number of space characters in any position
- may not contain any other kind of character
- the first two numerals must be one of the set: 02; 03; 07; 08; 13; 18
- and the number of numerals must be exactly 10 unless the first two numerals are 1 and 3, in which case the number of numerals may be 10 or 6.

Essentially these are Australian landline (with area code), free-call and 13 numbers.

Ideally the regex should be as implementation-agnostic as possible.

Examples of valid input:

- 0299998888
- 02 99998888
- 02 9999 8888
- 02 99 998 888
- 0299 998 888
- 0299 998888
- 131999
- 131 999
- 13 19 99
- 1300123456
- 1300 123456
- 1300 123 456
- 1300 12 34 56
- 1300 12 34  56

PS. I've checked at least 5 other answers and searched for multiple variations of this question, to no avail.

The nearest I have is:

```
^(?=\d{10}$)(02|03|04|07|08|13|18)\d+
```

... however this does not account for spacing and won't accept 6 digit numbers beginning with 13.

Note, in theory, the following is acceptable:

- 1 3 1999
- 1 3 1 9 9 9

By this I mean that first pair of numerals may have a space between them (as bad as that looks).

Following are examples of random numbers that should fail:

- 13145 (not enough numerals)
- 1300-123-456 (hyphens not permitted)
- 9999 8888 (not enough numerals)
- (02) 9999 8888 (parentheses not permitted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a separate pattern for `13` in alternation:

```
^(?:(?=(?:\s*\d\s*){10}$)(?:0\s*[2378]|1\s*[38])|(?=(?:\s*\d\s*){6}$)1\s*3).*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Hkjus2/2

Comment: Legend. I don't know how you do it but thank god for regex gurus :D